# Python3, Pandas and MySQL index issue

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pandas, indexing, sqlalchemy

I'm new on Python and trying to learn some basic Data Manipulation (the main focus is Data Science). So I'm still grasping Pandas and everything else.
What I'm trying to achieve, is to create a DataFrame and store it on a MySQL database. This is my script (that don't work):

```
from sqlalchemy.types import VARCHAR
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

frame = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((4,4)),
                 index=['val1','val2','val3','val4'],
                 columns=['col1','col2','col3','col4'])
engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://user:password@localhost/python_samples')
frame.to_sql('rnd_vals', engine, dtype={'index':VARCHAR(5)})
```

When I try to execute this, I get the error saying that MySQL won't allow to create a TEXT/BLOB index withouth the length:

```
InternalError: (pymysql.err.InternalError) (1170, "BLOB/TEXT column 'index' used in key specification without a key length") [SQL: 'CREATE INDEX ix_rnd_vals_index ON rnd_vals (`index`)']
```

I believed that I could fix this, by specifying the dtype option on the to_sql() function, but it didn't help.
I found a way of making this, by joining two DataFrames, one with the values, and the other one with the index:

```
from sqlalchemy.types import VARCHAR
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
frame = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(25).reshape(5,5),
                 columns=['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May'])
idxFrame = pd.DataFrame({'index':['exp1','exp2','exp3','exp4','exp5']})
frame = frame.join(idxFrame)
frame=frame.set_index('index')
    engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://user:password@localhost/python_samples')
frame.to_sql('indexes',engine,if_exists='replace', index_label='index',
         dtype={'index':VARCHAR(5)})
```

This works as expected, but I really doubt that this is the correct way of making this, can someone help me? What did I did wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Pretty sure that the problem in the 1st example is a name mismatch between how Pandas has named the index and your dtype mapping, but cannot check right now.

Comment: Given your first example, check what is `frame.index.name`.

Comment: Thank you Ilja Everilä, that solved. The index name was actually "None", so when I changed the dtype from {'index':VARCHAR(5)} to {'None':VARCHAR(5)}, it solved the issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For whoever is having this issue, Ilja Everilä on the comments solved the issue. The index name was actually 'None', instead of 'index', so when I changed the dtype from

```
dtype={'index':VARCHAR(5)}
```

to

```
dtype={'None':VARCHAR(5)}
```

It solved the issue, and the table was created on MySQL as:

```
CREATE TABLE `rnd_vals` (
  `index` text,
  `col1` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `col2` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `col3` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `col4` double DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

as expected.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find a direct way to enable pandas to directly import the index. In the end `reset_index()` seems the simplest method:

```
my_df.reset_index()
my_df.to_sql(name='my_table', con=engine, index=False, if_exists='replace')
```

Answer (score 0):

With :

```
frame.to_sql('rnd_vals', engine, dtype={'None':VARCHAR(5)})
```

It was giving :

1170, "BLOB/TEXT column 'index' used in key specification without a key length") [SQL: 'CREATE INDEX ix_indexes_index ON indexes (`index`)'] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)

This resolved the issue :

```
frame.to_sql('indexes',engine,if_exists='replace', index_label='index',dtype={frame.index.name:VARCHAR(5)})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to make an index from a column of type text/blob. In this case, MySQL unable to put uniqueness to the columns because of dynamic nature. There is no length associated with this. You can provide the type of column while saving dataframe to MySQL or (if you don't need an index) just make `index=False`.

Answer (score -2):

Use `VARCHAR(...)` instead of `TEXT` whenever practical.

In general, it is not useful to index `TEXT` columns.

I can't provide the sqlalchemy; I am not familiar with how it obfuscates the SQL code.

Comment: The issue here, is that I am using the VARCHAR() when I set the dtype (or so do I believe), so it seems that the sqlalchemy is ignoring this.

Comment: `<snide-remark>` Another case of 3rd party software getting in the way. `</snide-remark>`  File a bug report with sqlalchemy.